# Generate XML file documentation for Dynamic Abp Web Api

Tags: xml, metadata, swagger-ui, aspnetboilerplate

It is possible to auto-generate a XML comments documentation file for a dynamic Web API of Asp Net Boilerplate ?. How can I generate that file from the application layer?

For non-dynamic Web API, I am generating the xml comments documentation as follows.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3eCX.png)

And I add it to swagger-ui as follows

```
            Configuration.Modules.AbpWebApi().HttpConfiguration
                .EnableSwagger(c =>
                {
                    var dir = new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "SwaggerMetadata"));
                    if(dir.Exists) {
                        foreach (var fi in dir.EnumerateFiles("*.xml"))
                        {
                            c.IncludeXmlComments(fi.FullName);
                        }

                    }
}
```

Comment: swagger-ui is doing this for you.

Comment: In non-Dynamic web API. I am using the build-configuration output for generation of xml documentation file and add this xml in swagger-ui using Swashbuckle but i need generate xml comments documentation for the Dynamics Web APIs, this APIs not have project own.